# Why does one package declare another's activity in its own manifest?

Tags: android

As indicated by the tags, this is homework/classwork. (Note that it's really just an in class thing that my instructor can't seem to explain, so I'm turning to the interwebs).

We have an example made up of two apps: Sample1 and Sample2. The point of the example is to show calling into Sample2 from Sample1 using an intent. Sample 2 uses an intent filter to be launched by a certain intent. Here is a snipped from the manifest.

```
<activity
    android:name=".Sample2"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_Sample02" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="Sample02.intent.action.Thinger" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Sample01 invokes this using an intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("Sample02.intent.action.Thinger");
startActivity(intent);
```

This works fine, assuming that Sample02 is installed on the target device.

What confuses me is this bit in Sample01's manifest file:

```
<activity
android:name="com.example.Sample02.Sample02"
>
</activity>
```

I don't understand what this is for. It exists in addition to the  declaration for Sample01 in the same file. Near as I can tell, I can remove it and everything works the same. Anyone know what this about? Thanks.

Comment: a leftover? if you remove it and everything works, clearly it's not used

Comment: @Mat, I notice that you removed the "homework" tag. Not complaining, but it seemed like the most appropriate tag to indicate that this is classwork, which people seem to like to know. Wondered your motivation.

Comment: @SirPentor: see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/homework/info (the tag's wiki).

Comment: @Mat: Thanks. Boy, I feel foolish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is acknowledgment of simple02 app in simple01 app manifest. it is showing that we want to use simple02 method and function in simple01 app.

Comment: OK. Does the android system use it at all? Or is it really a comment?

Comment: just a type of comment but relevant when the other package removed from the system then it show error and give a warning to the user.